# How to find the ANOVA of a linear regression with log?

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression, anova

My Linear Model is having a patsy equation as "Y ~ np.log(X)"

How can I find the ANOVA(Analysis of variance) of the above linear regression equation in python using the statsmodels.anova library and further in finding the F-statistic value of the model

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols
import statsmodels.api as sm


df = pd.read_csv('csvfile')

df['X'] = np.log(df['X'])

model = ols('Y ~ X', data=df).fit() 
print(sm.stats.anova_lm(model, typ=2))
```

Comment: add some explanation please